# Simple SpringBoot service with single value JSONs fail

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, kotlin

I have the following RestController inside a kotlin (1.9.10) Spring Boot (3.1.5) application.

```kotlin
package io.company.connectors.fauxservice.actions

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class EchoAction {

    data class EchoActionOutput(
        val content: String,
    )

    data class EchoActionInput(
        val text: String,
    )

    data class EchoActionRequestBody(
        val inputs: EchoActionInput,
    )

    @PostMapping("/fauxservice/actions/echo/execute")
    fun execute(@RequestBody body: EchoActionRequestBody): EchoActionOutput {
        return EchoActionOutput(body.inputs.text)
    }
}
```

I try to hit the end point with the following POST request:

```json
{
    "inputs": {
      "text": "banana"
    }
}
```

And I expect this response:`{"content": "banana"}`

However, I am getting this (status `500` Internal Server Error):

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class io.company.connectors.fauxservice.actions.EchoAction$EchoActionRequestBody]...
```

I figured out that if I add additional optional parameters to my input objects, then it works as expected:

```kotlin
    data class EchoActionInput(
        val text: String,
        val empty: String?,
    )

    data class EchoActionRequestBody(
        val inputs: EchoActionInput,
        val empty: String?,
    )
```

If I only adjust the EchoActionRequestBody, then I receive the following error (status `400` Bad Request):

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `io.company.connectors.fauxservice.actions.EchoAction$EchoActionInput` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)...
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the right way to create single value data classes?

Comment: There must be something in your setup. I created a new project from Spring Initializr in Kotlin with the web dependency, added your class and it works like it should. Boot 3.1.5 and Kotlin 1.9.10.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch thanks indeed the error doesn't occur in a simple project. I have a two-layer project with multiple services inside. Here's a simplified project to reproduce the error: https://github.com/szedjani/springdemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson works by calling a default constructor and then setting each property one by one; in the cases where you have a single non-nullable field you aren't going to get a default constructor and then you are going to get issues.

Looking at your gradle build scripts they are very different from the standard ones generated by the Spring Initialiser (https://start.spring.io). You are better off generating your project using this as a template, as Spring will auotconfigure all the plugins needed for you to use normal data classes, as shown in your code. In essence, you are probably missing some Jackson configuration or kotlin specific Jackson plugins that a vanilla Spring Boot application generated by the initialiser is giving you for free.

For example, at the very least you'd need the jackson-module-kotlin as a dependency, and configure the default spring boot object mapper to register this, something that the Spring Boot starters would do for you.

Comment: I modified the generated project, because I had to create multiple sub-modules. This (github.com/szedjani/springdemo) is just a simplified version of the project, just to reproduce the issue.

Do you have more info on why I don't have a default constructor with a single non-nullable field, but I would get one if I have two non-nullable field?

The generated project doesn't list the jackson-module-kotlin as a dependency either though.

Comment: But nevertheless, you were right, just adding `implementation(com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.16.0)` to the `build.gradle.kts` of the relevant subproject solved the issue, I didn't even had to register it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to check this plugins in your configurations

```
plugins {
  ......
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
  kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
  kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.22"
}
```

Comment: It didn't solve the issue, the JVM and the Spring plugin was already added and the serialization plugin did not help. But I found the solution based on @PaulNUK's recommendation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77495990/simple-springboot-service-with-single-value-jsons-fail/77569377#comment136752504_77516729